# Angular - Test service subscribe on submit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

How  can i coverage test of submit action with subscribe event? i have this:

```js
onSubmit() {
    this.myService.myMethod(value)
      .subscribe((result: any) => {
        console.log(result);
      },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          console.log('completed);
        }
      );
}
```

**test**

```
it('should test submit',
    inject([myService, XHRBackend], (myService: any, mockBackend: any) => {
      const mockResponse = {
        error: false,
        msg: `Completed`
      };
      mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: any) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
          body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse)
        })));
      });
      myService.myMethod().subscribe(() => { });
    }));
```

My test coverage show that i haven't tested the subscribe lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few flaws in the component code of `onSubmit`. How can you test the outcome when you are just doing `console.log` etc. You need to handle some kind of flag and show/hide spinner or provide some error/success message. Then you can test the function with `error` and `success`. For example:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.showSpinner = true;
    this.myService.myMethod(value)
      .subscribe((result: any) => {
        this.msg = 'success';
      },
        error => {
          this.msg = 'error';
        },
        () => {
          this.showSpinner = false;
        }
      );
}
```

in **test** file:

```
class MySvcMock{
  myMethod() { return of('someVal')}
}

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       provider: [{provide: MyService, useClass: MySvcMock}]        
    }).compileComponents();
...
...

it('should set success msg on submit',()=>{
   component.msg = '';
   component.onSubmit();
   expect(component.msg).toBe('success');
   expect(component.showSpinner).toBeFalsy();
})

it('should set error msg on submit error',()=>{
   component.msg = '';
   spyOn(component.myService,'myMethod').and.returnValue(throwError('some error msg'));
   component.onSubmit();
   expect(component.msg).toBe('error');
   expect(component.showSpinner).toBeFalsy();
})
```

You can refer to my series of article which can help you get more familiar with Karma.

1. [Intro to Karma. check the links at the bottom of article](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7)
2. [This is the one which will help you in this scenario](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49)